# links not working in my jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile web app and have different seperated pages and some with multipages inside.

The footer contains links to the external pages. When im trying to put an anchor link, it wont work. Any solution?

Here are the codes for my footer and my anchor

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="myfooter">

        <div data-role="navbar" id="mainnavbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a rel="external" href="home.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-icon-fa"><img src="../img/icons/home@2x.png"></a></li>
                <li><a rel="external" href="search.html" ><img src="../img/icons/lista@2x.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#chooser" ><img src="../img/icons/watto@2x.png" width="36" height="36"></a></li>
                <li><a rel="external" href="location.html"><img src="../img/icons/location@2x.png"></a></li>
                <li><a rel="external" href="settings.html" ><img src="../img/icons/profile@2x.png"></a></li>

    </div>


</div>
```

Anchor code:

```
   <div role="main" class="ui-content">

            <div id="logo">

                <img src="../img/LogoSF.png" style="text-align:center" height="auto" width="60%">

            </div>    

            <div id="contenido">

                <h1> Bienvenido a Chooser </h1>

                <p> Estas a 10 preguntas de encontrar tu plan ideal. </p>


                <div id="continuar">

                <a href="#1" class="ui-btn">A</a>

                </div>

            </div>
```

any solutions?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle.?

Comment: What is that? Sorry I'm new

Comment: Hi it's about preparing the code running example so others can view your running example and can help you by finding where you are actually having problem here is type of example http://jsfiddle.net/fatCop/jpes2wry/

Comment: use click event and there use change page with relative path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the ajax link behaviour from an anchor tag, you can put rel=external in the link and the link will load without ajax and your url will then be usual.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html
like :

```
<a href="User/somepage" rel="external" />I wont be using ajax for navigation</a>
```

and here is solution using jquery

```
$(function(){
  $(".content a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("rel","external");
  });
});
```